# Testing AlertDialog/`showDialog` in a widget test ("Which: means none were found but one was expected")

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm trying to write a widget test to ensure an `AlertDialog` is shown to the user.

I've got a small example to reproduce this. When manually used by a user, the widget shows the AlertDialog, but it fails to show in a widget test.

[image]

**I've tried a few things:**

- Using different methods to retrieve the button: `find.byKey`, `find.byIcon`,
- Using different methods to press the button: `tester.tap`, `tester.press`
- Using some arbitrary delay after pressing the button: `await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));`
- Checking different expected elements: `expect(find.byElementType(AlertDialog), findsOneWidget);`, putting a distinct icon e.g. pokeball and getting it: `expect(find.byIcon(Icons.catching_pokemon), findsOneWidget)`
- Setting `useDialog`'s `useRootNavigator:false`
- tip: if you run `flutter run main.dart`, it will run test visually on the device screen
- tip 2: you can run the app by commenting out some code (see `main` function)

### Short example

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const buttonKey = Key("button");
const alertDialogKey = Key("alertDialog");

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  showAppDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    print("Showing app dialog");
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            key: alertDialogKey,
            title: const Text(
              "You can see this dialog, but you can't catch it with WidgetTester.",
            ),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.catching_pokemon),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: const Text("Oops"),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dialog',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return TextButton(
          key: buttonKey,
          child: const Text("Show dialog"),
          onPressed: () async => await showAppDialog(context),
        );
      }))),
    );
  }
}

void mainTest() {
  testWidgets(
    "When button is pressed, dialog is shown.",
    (tester) async {
      final widget = MyApp();
      await tester.pumpWidget(widget);

      final button = find.byKey(buttonKey);
      expect(button, findsOneWidget);

      await tester.press(button);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      // None of these work:
      expect(find.byKey(alertDialogKey), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byIcon(Icons.catching_pokemon), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byElementType(AlertDialog), findsOneWidget);
    },
  );
}

void main() {
  // Uncomment to run the app manually
  // runApp(MyApp());
  // Comment out to run the app manually.
  mainTest();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do **2 things**:

- Trigger the button inside `await tester.runAsync(() async {})` because `showDialog` is an async function. By default, Flutter doesn't actually run asynchronous work in tests, for performance reasons.
- use `tester.tap` instead of `tester.press` because `press` doesn't actually release button, so **`.press` doesn't trigger `onPressed` callback** .

```dart
void mainTest() {
  testWidgets(
    "When button is pressed, dialog is shown.",
    (tester) async {
      final widget = MyApp();
      await tester.pumpWidget(widget);

      final button = find.byKey(buttonKey);
      expect(button, findsOneWidget);

      await tester.runAsync(() async {
        await tester.tap(button);
//         Or alternatively press then "up":
//         final response = await tester.press(button);
//         await response.up();
      });
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      // These all work now
      expect(find.byKey(alertDialogKey), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byIcon(Icons.catching_pokemon), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byType(AlertDialog), findsOneWidget);
    },
  );
}
```

***Extra tip:** run your tests on a device to visualise what's happening. Run `flutter run test/name_of_test.dart`*. This helps you see where the problem is: for example, is it the `AlertDialog` not showing, or the `find.byType` not finding the `AlertDialog`?

Comment: But test still fails

Comment: Test passes for me .

Comment: You can run the tests on my dartpad pad: https://dartpad.dev/?a7e19a0233f716dd3b849d5d1f71bde9. It passed for me.

Comment: seems link is broken

Comment: Oh, I needed to name the file `main.dart` in the gist, and weirdly I only saw the issue when I was in a private window. Fixed: https://dartpad.dev/?id=a7e19a0233f716dd3b849d5d1f71bde9

Comment: I still can't use `byElementType` though. I'm using `byKey()` instead, which is a bit redundant since I'll always only have 1 `AlertDialog` shown.  Ohhh, I should use `byType`, not `byElementType`

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue and all I needed to do was remove the 'await' from when I 'showDialog'. The reason for this seams to be that the pumpAndSettle is awaiting for the dialog to close before it continues, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using:

```
await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently but now it's working, this is the end code for the test part:

```
    testWidgets('A modal is open when the user clicks on FilterButton', (tester) async {

  await tester.pumpWidget(
    const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: FilterButton(),
    )),
  );

  await tester.tap(find.byType(ElevatedButton));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  expect(find.byType(AlertDialog), findsWidgets);
});
```

For reference, here's a simplified version of my actual widget, **the "MultiSelectModal" is the class that contains the AlertDialog:**

```
class FilterButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilterButton({super.key});

  @override
  State<FilterButton> createState() => _FilterButtonState();
}

class _FilterButtonState extends State<FilterButton> {

  Future<void> _showMultiSelectModal() async {
      await showDialog<List<String>>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const MultiSelectModal();
        },
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey)),
              onPressed: () => _showMultiSelectModal(),
              child: const Row(children: [
                Icon(Icons.filter_list),
                SizedBox(width: 5),
                Text('Filtros'),
              ]),
            );

  }
}
```